# C1083 Cannot open source file (but no reference to source file in code?)

Tags: c++, linker, include

Bit of an odd one here (to me at least).

I was starting a Flight Sim X SimConnect project in VS2015. I made sure the linker was pointed to the SimConnect.lib and that the additional include directories were linked to the include file of the SimConnect library.

Then I included the file at the beginning of one of my classes, but I never used it (I was coding some ui elements first).

Anyway, I'm trying to compile the project but it keeps screaming at me:

```
    1>cl : Command line warning D9030: '/Yc' is incompatible with multiprocessing; ignoring /MP switch
1>  SimConnect.lib
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'SimConnect.lib': No such file or directory
1>  pch.cpp
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Now, for one I'm stuck as to why it can't see the lib, I've followed all the standard procedures to link it to the linker.

But more confusingly I've removed the #include to the SimConnect.h and I'm not using a single method or variable from the library...

I've even tried removing all reference to it in the project settings but to no avail.

Does anyone know either:

A) Why the linker isn't seeing the file I definitely linked it to
B) Why it is still screaming even though I've cleansed my simple two class project of any reference to the library?

Thanks

Guy

Comment: Did you add its name to the linker inputs while forgetting to add its parent directory to the library directories?

Comment: *"Cannot open **source file**: 'SimConnect.lib'"* This is not a linker error, but a compiler error. Seems like you have the lib added as a source file, and not as a library.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I switched to running it in x64 mode and it compiled first time. strange, perhaps the library is not compatible with x86? Would this be common behavior?